# Convert Column values of a single row into 2 columns with the column headers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert Column and a row into 2 columns.
Below is the sample Table [Table01] with 4 columns and a single row.

```
First   Second  Third   Forth
01      02      03      04
```

I need to Transpose it as a new table [Table01_T]

```
Column01     Column02
First         01
Second        02
Third         03
Forth         04
```

Every time we receive a single row with 4 columns and we need them to convert in 2 columns and four rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
select
  v.*
from [Table01]
 cross apply
  (values ('First', [First]),('Second',[Second]),
          ('Third',[Third]),('Forth',[Forth])) v(Column01, Column02);
```

Using the same sample data this query produces the same results.  I find this syntax to be more readable then UNPIVOT.

Results

```
Column1 Column02
First   01
Second  02
Third   03
Forth   04
```

Comment: Readability is subjective, of course. I prefer `UNPIVOT` because I find `'First', [First]` redundant and clumsy. :-)

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand, this question is a nice little referendum on the two techniques!  For me CROSS APPLY is like stacking bricks, it's easy.  With UNPIVOT, which I used for a long time, it always involved BOL.  It definitely is subjective tho :)  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT Column01, Column02
  -- INTO dbo.Table01_T
  FROM dbo.Table01 
  UNPIVOT 
    (                         -- vvvvv column names you want to turn to rows
      Column02 FOR Column01 IN ([First],[Second],[Third],[Fourth])
  --               ^^^^^^^^ becomes column name from each original column 
  --  ^^^^^^^^ becomes column value from each original column
    ) AS u;
```

Isolated example using a table variable:

```
DECLARE @x table([First] char(2),Second char(2),Third char(2),Fourth char(2));
INSERT @x([First],[Second],[Third],[Fourth]) VALUES ('01','02','03','04');

SELECT Column01, Column02
  FROM @x UNPIVOT 
  (
    Column02 FOR Column01 IN ([First],[Second],[Third],[Fourth])
  ) AS u;
```

Results:

```
Column01    Column02
--------    --------
First       01
Second      02
Third       03
Fourth      04
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7c07d30414b217cbf383b5974ffd2f8)